# patch the same object with the right return

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pytest

I'm looking for the possibility to patch the same object 2 times, but in a different method, I made an example for more understanding. for a very specific reason is that I'm trying to do this with a monkeypatch and not just change the attribute with a reattribution such as : foo.bar ="fobar2". If that is possible or not. Thank you in advance

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = str()
        self.bar = str()
    def foo(self):
        self.bar = requests.get('https://foobar.com')
        return self.bar

    def foo2(self):
        self.bar2 = requests.get('https://foobar2.com')
        return self.bar2

def test_bar(monkeypatch):
    def mockreturn(requests):
        return "fobar"
    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', mockreturn)
    foo = Foo()
    assert foo.foo() == 'fobar'
    assert foo.foo2() == "fobar2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting a return value for get, try making it a function. Something like this perhaps:

```
def mock_get(url):
    url_response_map = {'https://foobar.com': 'fobar'. 'https://foobar2.com': 'foobar2'}
    return url_response_map(url)

monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', mock_get)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,it's perfect :D